# aligning elements in same line in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, html

I am trying to align 2 elements in the same line next to each other, but having hard time. And i know this is kind of a simple question that can be googled. But i simply can't seem to do it.

Here is the code -

```
<div>
  <c:PF_InputCheckbox id="pf_nhw_contractor_submit_acknowledged" value="{!v.acknowledged}"/>
  I affirm I have read and understand the policy.
</div>
```

Here is the output -
[image]

The component c:PF_InputCheckbox is that checkbox thingy seen here. I want the text right next to it, not below it.

I have tried assigning class slds-show_inline-block to container div, but it still shows the checkbox and the text in two separate lines.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways of doing this. One of them would be using an [slds grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/)

```
<div class="slds-grid">
  <div class="slds-col"> Component HERE</div>
  <div class="slds-col"> Text HERE </div>
</div>
```

would render the following:

[image]
you can then chose to align your text to the left, or right, again using slds. I encourage you to read the the SLDS documentation and or to do the [SLDS Trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_design_system) to expand your knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

For use cases like this SLDS provides Name => Value pairs, as [described here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/name-value-list/#content)

With just one class (`slds-list_horizontal`), you can change the layout as needed, so they can be stacked, as you have it right now:

[image]

You could also align all of them inline:

[image]

Or align Name->Value pairs horizontal as you need it:
[image]

Your markup would look like this:

```
<dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak>I affirm I have read and understand the policy.</dt>
  <dd class="slds-item_detail">
    <c:PF_InputCheckbox id="pf_nhw_contractor_submit_acknowledged" value="{!v.acknowledged}"/>
  </dd>
</dl>
```